# How do I load a module that has no signature in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, kernel, webcam

I've got a custom module for a Mightex camera that has been tested for ubuntu 12.04 which I'm using.

I have installed it however something is not working. I think it has to do with this `dmesg` output:

```
[    5.766665] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Mightex
[   13.790378] Mightex: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
```

Other info that might be useful is:

- **UPDATE3** below is probably the most useful
- There is no `/dev/video1` (video0 is my webcam)
- `lsmod | grep -i mightex` gives 2 entries:

  - `Mightex                64952  0`
  - `videodev              139761  3 uvcvideo,Mightex,videobuf2_core`
- `lsusb` output:

  - `Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04b4:0228 Cypress Semiconductor Corp.`

After googling a bit I found this link which seems to be the problem but I don't understand how I can fix this. Any help would be much appreciated

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975377/kvm-module-verification-failed-signature-and-or-required-key-missing-taintin

If you want me to post other info let me know.

**UPDATE**

Here is some more relevant info from `dmesg | grep -i video`:

```
[   14.893212] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   15.113088] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 718 at /build/buildd/linux-lts-trusty-3.13.0/drivers/media/v4l2-core/v4l2-dev.c:779 __video_register_device+0x452/0x540 [videodev]()
[   15.113095] Modules linked in: Mightex(OX+) snd_seq hp_wmi(+) mac80211 videobuf2_core sparse_keymap ttm videodev videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops ath9k_common snd_timer ath9k_hw snd_seq_device drm_kms_helper ath drm rtsx_pci_ms psmouse k10temp memstick serio_raw snd cfg80211 soundcore i2c_piix4 snd_page_alloc i2c_algo_bit hp_accel lis3lv02d video mac_hid input_polldev wmi hp_wireless lp parport hid_generic usbhid hid rtsx_pci_sdmmc r8169 mii rtsx_pci ahci libahci
[   15.113832]  [<ffffffffa02a0672>] __video_register_device+0x452/0x540 [videodev]
[   15.114362] video_register_device failed
```

Also, I tried disabling *Secure Boot* as per [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#SecureBoot) however this didn't change anything.

**UPDATE2**

This line here: `[   15.114362] video_register_device failed` is caused by this bit of code:

```
if (video_register_device(usbMightex->vdev, VFL_TYPE_GRABBER, video_nr) <0)
{
    pr_err("video_register_device failed");
}
```

**UPDATE3**

I think this is the actual module crashing and the output for debugging purposes?

```
[   14.113728] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[   14.113739] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 755 at /build/buildd/linux-lts-trusty-3.13.0/drivers/media/v4l2-core/v4l2-dev.c:779 __video_register_device+0x452/0x540 [videodev]()
[   14.113741] Modules linked in: Mightex(OX+) snd_hda_codec_idt snd_hda_codec_hdmi ath9k_common uvcvideo snd_hda_intel ath9k_hw snd_hda_codec videobuf2_core videodev videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_rawmidi snd_seq_midi_event snd_seq snd_timer snd_seq_device ath snd soundcore ttm drm_kms_helper drm cfg80211 i2c_piix4 hp_wmi sparse_keymap i2c_algo_bit joydev snd_page_alloc rtsx_pci_ms k10temp psmouse hp_accel hp_wireless wmi lis3lv02d input_polldev serio_raw memstick video mac_hid lp parport hid_generic usbhid hid rtsx_pci_sdmmc r8169 ahci libahci rtsx_pci mii
[   14.113784] CPU: 0 PID: 755 Comm: modprobe Tainted: G           OX 3.13.0-43-generic #72~precise1-Ubuntu
[   14.113787] Hardware name: Hewlett-Packard HP Pavilion g7 Notebook PC/184B, BIOS F.26 02/21/2013
[   14.113789]  000000000000030b ffff8800b6005b68 ffffffff81757f91 000000000000337e
[   14.113793]  0000000000000000 ffff8800b6005ba8 ffffffff8106afcc ffff880115756400
[   14.113798]  ffff8800bd16c800 00000000ffffffff ffffffffa032a3a8 00000000ffffffea
[   14.113801] Call Trace:
[   14.113810]  [<ffffffff81757f91>] dump_stack+0x46/0x58
[   14.113817]  [<ffffffff8106afcc>] warn_slowpath_common+0x8c/0xc0
[   14.113821]  [<ffffffff8106b01a>] warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20
[   14.113827]  [<ffffffffa02b1672>] __video_register_device+0x452/0x540 [videodev]
[   14.113833]  [<ffffffffa0323b89>] Mightex_probe+0x1f9/0x4f0 [Mightex]
[   14.113838]  [<ffffffff81571180>] usb_probe_interface+0x1c0/0x2f0
[   14.113843]  [<ffffffff814b5c01>] really_probe+0x91/0x380
[   14.113847]  [<ffffffff814b6077>] driver_probe_device+0x47/0xa0
[   14.113850]  [<ffffffff814b617b>] __driver_attach+0xab/0xb0
[   14.113853]  [<ffffffff814b60d0>] ? driver_probe_device+0xa0/0xa0
[   14.113857]  [<ffffffff814b3eee>] bus_for_each_dev+0x5e/0x90
[   14.113860]  [<ffffffff814b57be>] driver_attach+0x1e/0x20
[   14.113864]  [<ffffffff814b52c4>] bus_add_driver+0x124/0x260
[   14.113867]  [<ffffffff814b6894>] driver_register+0x64/0xf0
[   14.113872]  [<ffffffff8156fd10>] usb_register_driver+0xa0/0x160
[   14.113876]  [<ffffffffa02e2000>] ? 0xffffffffa02e1fff
[   14.113880]  [<ffffffffa02e201e>] usb_Mightex_init+0x1e/0x1000 [Mightex]
[   14.113884]  [<ffffffff8100215a>] do_one_initcall+0xfa/0x1b0
[   14.113888]  [<ffffffff8105cb03>] ? set_memory_nx+0x43/0x50
[   14.113894]  [<ffffffff8174ccba>] do_init_module+0x80/0x1d1
[   14.113898]  [<ffffffff810e8261>] load_module+0x4e1/0x600
[   14.113901]  [<ffffffff810e5920>] ? show_initstate+0x50/0x50
[   14.113904]  [<ffffffff810e8434>] SyS_init_module+0xb4/0x100
[   14.113908]  [<ffffffff8176d66d>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
[   14.113911] ---[ end trace 829b68775c8efe92 ]---
```